# Mysql use of alias table in where clause subquery

Tags: mysql

I've made some research but didn't find any answers to my question

Here it goes :

First of all I've managed to make my query work but I don't find it beautiful so that's why I'm comming here to see if I can code it better.

to summerise the query, this is what I want to do

```
SELECT *  
FROM (/* big query with subqueries and UNION of big query with subqueries */) AS fake_table
WHERE position IN (SELECT MAX(position) FROM fake_table)
```

but it doesn't want to have a table alias in the subselect of the clause it say : Table 'blabla.fake' doesn't exist. I have to copy the complete big query in the clause subselect

do you guys have an idea ?

Many thx for your help

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a temp table or table variable?

Comment: No reason, what do you propose ?

Comment: Or create a view for 'fake_table'? Seriously - it makes it easier to understand, debug and test. It is also easier to maintain for others who follow you? The database engine will try and optimize it. You need to look at the explain plan for the different queries to see what is happening. Also, It may not be slower than using one query. Think of it as 'refactoring' in the same manner that you do for code?

Comment: Ah maby a view would be a good idea in this case, but that doesn't answer the question it would probably solve the ''good code'' problem

Comment: It does answer the question. If you create a view or a temp table, your query works. `SELECT * FROM fake_table_view WHERE position IN (SELECT MAX(position) FROM fake_table_view)` won't produce an error anymore.

Comment: good practice would be more exact then good code

Comment: yea i'm looking now to translate my fake table with clauses into a view

Comment: Does `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (subquery) as fake_table ORDER BY position DESC` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: No the query can return more then 1 element

Comment: Ah ok, I thought position might be unique.

Comment: Why can't you make the fake table into a view? You have not really answered this completely sensible question!

Comment: I never said I can't make it, just said it was a good idea. I'm looking forward to do this write now. 
I know this would answer the problem of ''good practice coding'' but i'm curios to understand why mysql doesn't see the fake_table alias in the subquery. the scope should extend from inside to out of the query to me

Comment: Well I've made the view and got my code cleaner. I don't have an answer about why I can't use the table alias in the subquery but I thx all you guys for the help.